# Is there a way to display percent of white space (Empty space) present in the columns in R via visualization?

Tags: r

I have few  variables that has empty/White space in my dataset.I was curious if there is a way I can  plot the percent of white space that is present in my column. I have heard of `visdat()` package. However, that package doesn't display the percentage of Whitespace/empty column in dataset. It only display percent of 'N/A' present in column.
Below is my sample of my dataset

```
> dput(tail(few_var,5))
structure(list(`Hotel Name-Long_PL` = c("Hyatt Place at Anaheim Resort/Convention Center", 
"Hyatt Place at Anaheim Resort/Convention Center", "Hyatt Place at Anaheim Resort/Convention Center", 
"Hyatt Place at Anaheim Resort/Convention Center", "Hyatt Place at Anaheim Resort/Convention Center"
), State_PL = c("California", "California", "California", "California", 
"California"), City_PL = c("Anaheim", "Anaheim", "Anaheim", "Anaheim", 
"Anaheim"), `Postal Code_PL` = c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_, NA_integer_), Condition_Hotel_H = c(10L, 10L, 8L, 
10L, 10L), NPS_Type = c("Detractor", "Passive", "Detractor", 
"Promoter", "Promoter"), `Property Latitude_PL` = c(33.835293, 
33.835293, 33.835293, 33.835293, 33.835293), `Property Longitude_PL` = c(-117.914504, 
-117.914504, -117.914504, -117.914504, -117.914504), `Mini-Bar_PL` = c("", 
"", "", "", ""), `Pool-Indoor_PL` = c("", "", "", "", ""), `Pool-Outdoor_PL` = c("", 
"", "", "", ""), `Fitness Center_PL` = c("", "", "", "", ""), 
    `Shuttle Service_PL` = c("", "", "", "", ""), Spa_PL = c("", 
    "", "", "", ""), Casino_PL = c("", "", "", "", ""), POV_H = c("Leisure", 
    "Leisure", "Leisure", "Combination of both business and leisure", 
    "Leisure"), LENGTH_OF_STAY_C = c(1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L)), .Names = c("Hotel Name-Long_PL", 
"State_PL", "City_PL", "Postal Code_PL", "Condition_Hotel_H", 
"NPS_Type", "Property Latitude_PL", "Property Longitude_PL", 
"Mini-Bar_PL", "Pool-Indoor_PL", "Pool-Outdoor_PL", "Fitness Center_PL", 
"Shuttle Service_PL", "Spa_PL", "Casino_PL", "POV_H", "LENGTH_OF_STAY_C"
), row.names = c(3923613L, 3923616L, 3923631L, 3923639L, 3923646L
), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))
```

Any help is appreciated!Thanks in advance!

Comment: Assing `NA` to your whitespaces and apply the function

Comment: Not sure about the downvotes. I think we should encourage new users by upvoting questions that include sample data and a clearly stated problem. This question has both, and IMO is better than the majority of questions I come across from new SO members. At the very least please provide some comments so that OP has a chance to improve the quality of his/her question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

```
sapply(df, function(x) sum(x == "")/length(x) * 100);
#   Hotel Name-Long_PL              State_PL               City_PL
#                    0                     0                     0
#       Postal Code_PL     Condition_Hotel_H              NPS_Type
#                   NA                     0                     0
# Property Latitude_PL Property Longitude_PL           Mini-Bar_PL
#                    0                     0                   100
#       Pool-Indoor_PL       Pool-Outdoor_PL     Fitness Center_PL
#                  100                   100                   100
#   Shuttle Service_PL                Spa_PL             Casino_PL
#                  100                   100                   100
#                POV_H      LENGTH_OF_STAY_C
#                    0                     0
```

Similarly for calculating the percentage of `NA`s per column:

```
sapply(df, function(x) sum(is.na(x))/length(x) * 100);
#   Hotel Name-Long_PL              State_PL               City_PL
#                    0                     0                     0
#       Postal Code_PL     Condition_Hotel_H              NPS_Type
#                  100                     0                     0
# Property Latitude_PL Property Longitude_PL           Mini-Bar_PL
#                    0                     0                     0
#       Pool-Indoor_PL       Pool-Outdoor_PL     Fitness Center_PL
#                    0                     0                     0
#   Shuttle Service_PL                Spa_PL             Casino_PL
#                    0                     0                     0
#                POV_H      LENGTH_OF_STAY_C
#                    0                     0
```

---

### Sample data

```
df <- structure(list(`Hotel Name-Long_PL` = c("Hyatt Place at Anaheim Resort/Convention Center",
"Hyatt Place at Anaheim Resort/Convention Center", "Hyatt Place at Anaheim Resort/Convention Center",
"Hyatt Place at Anaheim Resort/Convention Center", "Hyatt Place at Anaheim Resort/Convention Center"
), State_PL = c("California", "California", "California", "California",
"California"), City_PL = c("Anaheim", "Anaheim", "Anaheim", "Anaheim",
"Anaheim"), `Postal Code_PL` = c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_,
NA_integer_, NA_integer_), Condition_Hotel_H = c(10L, 10L, 8L,
10L, 10L), NPS_Type = c("Detractor", "Passive", "Detractor",
"Promoter", "Promoter"), `Property Latitude_PL` = c(33.835293,
33.835293, 33.835293, 33.835293, 33.835293), `Property Longitude_PL` = c(-117.914504,
-117.914504, -117.914504, -117.914504, -117.914504), `Mini-Bar_PL` = c("",
"", "", "", ""), `Pool-Indoor_PL` = c("", "", "", "", ""), `Pool-Outdoor_PL` = c("",
"", "", "", ""), `Fitness Center_PL` = c("", "", "", "", ""),
    `Shuttle Service_PL` = c("", "", "", "", ""), Spa_PL = c("",
    "", "", "", ""), Casino_PL = c("", "", "", "", ""), POV_H = c("Leisure",
    "Leisure", "Leisure", "Combination of both business and leisure",
    "Leisure"), LENGTH_OF_STAY_C = c(1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L)), .Names = c("Hotel Name-Long_PL",
"State_PL", "City_PL", "Postal Code_PL", "Condition_Hotel_H",
"NPS_Type", "Property Latitude_PL", "Property Longitude_PL",
"Mini-Bar_PL", "Pool-Indoor_PL", "Pool-Outdoor_PL", "Fitness Center_PL",
"Shuttle Service_PL", "Spa_PL", "Casino_PL", "POV_H", "LENGTH_OF_STAY_C"
), row.names = c(3923613L, 3923616L, 3923631L, 3923639L, 3923646L
), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Instead of blindly downvoting, please provide some comments as to why you think this does *not* answer the question.

Comment: ...Perfect This is what I was looking for. Thanks for help!

Comment: @YesBoss No problem, glad to help. Don't get put off by the downvotes. I think your question was fine, you provided sample data and a clear problem. That's better than the majority of questions from new SO members around here!

Comment: Thanks for positive comment. I was about to delete my question, due to downvotes. Again appreciate your help!Thanks!